# Dual association between two ActiveRecord models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, form-helpers

I have sites and pages. Sites have many pages and each page belongs to a site. On top of that, I would like to assign one page to be the default for each site. The most efficient way I can think about this is to save the default page ID in the site model.

Here's what I have

```
#schema
create_table "pages", force: true do |t|
  t.integer  "site_id"
  ...

create_table "sites", force: true do |t|
  t.integer  "default_page_id"
  ...

#site.rb
class Site < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pages

#page.rb
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :site

# this already works

s = Site.new ...
p1 = Page.new ...
p2 = Page.new ...

s.pages << p1
s.pages << p2

s.pages #=> should return the site's pages
p1.site # => should return the site the page belongs to
```

How can I make this kind of interface work? Or feel free to propose a better one.

```
s.default_page = p1

s.default_page #=> should return the site default page

p1.default_on_site #=> should return the site where the page is default
```

**Update:**

Decided to go with default_page_id provided by AR and add

```
def default_page
  @default_page ||= if self.default_page_id
    Page.where(id: self.default_page_id).first
  else
    nil
  end
end

def default_page_url
  self.default_page.nil? ? "" : self.default_page.url
end
```

which allows for easy access in the view

```
 # form_for @site
 <%= f.collection_select :default_page_id, @site.pages, :id, :url, {include_blank: true}, {class: "form-control"} %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define some instance methods in your Site and Page models.
In your Site model:

```
Class Site
    def set_default_page(dp)
      self.default_page_id = dp.id
    end

    def get_default_page
      Page.find(self.default_page_id)
    end
end
```

In your Page model:

```
Class Page

    def default_on_site
      self.site
    end

End
```

If you want more generalized class methods, you should check out [scopes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes).

Comment: I was wondering if there was a way to use active record to create the interface... If I cannot find one, I will definitely use this option.